# Why does MySQL drop '\' before utf-8 encoded characters?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I am storing data, which contains characters other than A-Z, in a MySQL database. When a non A-Z character is stored (ex. `\u201cboard\u201d` that is "board", appears like `u201cboardu201d`), MySQL drops `'\'` which makes the text a complete non-sense bunch of letters and numbers impossible to read. I am using `utf8_general_ci` encoding.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MySQL does not yet support unicode literals, which is what I'd call `\uxxxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to explicitly specify the encoding along with the credentials when connecting to MySQL database. I am using Python so in my case I had to do it like this:

```
(host="host", user="user", passwd="pass", db="mydb", charset='utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

backslash is special symbol for MySQL, try to use double back slash instead ('\\' instead of '\')

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes you are right, but when I store the data, it automatically encodes it using single '\', but assume I replace it each time with '\\' and store it. MySQL drops one '\', but then when I retreive it, it again returns '\\' in front of the character, which I can again replace with '\', but is there any more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't store \u... stuff, store utf8.

If you are coming from PHP, note the extra arg:

```
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: I am using Python "utf-8" encoding.

Comment: The \u encoding is coming from somewhere; it is not utf8.